# Two near-identical pieces of code.. one works, the other doesn't

Tags: php

The following code works fine, it randomly selects an image from a folder, and assigns it as a background to a generated Div. This works. If I use this code a second time, but use it to simply place an img-src of the randomised image, this also works. However, using the code in the same way as the first, breaks the site. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <!-- BEGIN FEATURED 1 -->

                             <?php
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo 'Could not establish a connection to the database.';
}

$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT `articleid`,`title`  FROM `news_articles` WHERE  featured = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$array = array(
    'N'
);
$query->execute();

$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
foreach ($results as $row) {
}

$image = get_rand_img('images/featured_images/csgo/');
$title = $result['title'];
echo '<a href="index.php?viewarticle=1&articleid=' . $row . '">';?>
<div id="featured-image" style="height: 267px; width: 292px; background:url(/images/featured_images/csgo/<?php echo $image ?>)">
<?php

$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT `articleid`,`title`,`short_title` FROM `news_articles` WHERE articleid=$row");
    $result->execute();
    $rows = $result->fetch();
        echo '<div class="featuredtitle1">';
        echo $rows['short_title'];
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</a>';

?>
```

The code below, breaks the site.. (I have commented it out at the moment as you can see).

```
<!-- BEGIN FEATURED 2 (Disabled) -->

            <?php
/*
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo 'Could not establish a connection to the database.';
}

$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT `articleid` FROM `news_articles` WHERE  featured = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$array = array(
    'N'
);
$query->execute();

$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
foreach ($results as $row) {
}

$image = get_rand_img('images/featured_images/dota/');
$title = $result['title'];
echo '<a href="index.php?viewarticle=1&articleid=' . $row . '">';?>
<div id="featured-image2" style="height: 267px; width: 292px; background:url(/images/featured_images/dota/<?php echo $image ?>)">
<?php

$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT `articleid`,`title`,`short_title` FROM `news_articles` WHERE articleid=$row");
    $result->execute();
    $rows = $result->fetch();
        echo '<div class="featuredtitle2">';
        echo $rows['short_title'];
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</a>';
*/
?>
```

I don't understand why the first piece of code is fine, but duplicating it again breaks it?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 953

Comment: which is `$ext = end(explode('.', $file)); if ($ext == 'gif' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'png' || $ext == 'GIF' || $ext == 'JPEG' || $ext == 'JPG' || $ext == 'PNG') {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you edited your comment, I saw a fatal error about accessing object as an array. Try to change your code from this:

```
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

To this:

```
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Ok well I simply removed $title = $result['title']; and the above code now works.. I will do as you say though to optimise further.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that you accessed $result as an array, but it was an object. The code I proposed will actually give you an array instead.